# Differentiating from the first principle

Tags: calculus

How do I convincingly differentiate $\sin 3x$ or any trig function that comes in the form $\tan nx$, $\sin nx$, $\cos nx$ from the first principle?

I have tried expanding some forms using some trig identities but the $n$ coefficient isn't just showing up

Comment: See [here](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-sincos-2009-1.pdf), and replace $x$ with $3x$.

Comment: The answer is equal to the differentiation of the sine wave keeping the angle the same times the differentiaiton of the angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the usual way. You use trigonometric identities. For example:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sin{(nx)}\right]=
\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\sin{[n(x+\Delta x)]}-\sin{(nx)}}{\Delta x}=\\
\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{2\sin{\left(n\frac{x+\Delta x-x}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(n\frac{x+\Delta x+x}{2}\right)}}{\Delta x}=\\
n\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\sin{\left(n\frac{\Delta x}{2}\right)}}{n\frac{\Delta x}{2}}\cdot\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\left[\cos{\left(nx+n\frac{\Delta x}{2}\right)}\right].
$$

Let $t=n\frac{\Delta x}{2}$, then $\Delta x\to0\implies t\to0$.

$$
n\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\cdot\lim_{t\to0}\left[\cos{\left(nx+t\right)}\right]=
n\cdot1\cdot\cos{(nx+0)}=\\
=n\cos{(nx)}.
$$

And you do a similar thing for the cosine function. When you're going to do the tangent and cotangent functions, don't forget that they are defined in terms of the cosine and sine functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow the trigonometric functions to be defined by their McLauren series, then you can differentiate these term-by-term.

For example:

$$\cos nx = 1 - \frac{(nx)^2}{2!} + \frac{(nx)^4}{4!}-\frac{(nx)^6}{6!}+\cdots$$

$$
\frac{d\cos nx}{dx} =  - \frac{2n(nx)}{2!} + \frac{4n(nx)^3}{4!}-\frac{6n(nx)^5}{6!}+\cdots$$

$$
\frac{d\cos nx}{dx} =  - n(nx) + \frac{n(nx)^3}{3!}-\frac{n(nx)^5}{5!} 
+\cdots= -n \sin nx$$

Also

$$ \tan nx = nx + \frac{1}{3} (nx)^3 + \frac{2}{15} (nx)^5 + \frac{17}{315}(nx)^7+\cdots$$

$$\frac{d \tan nx}{dx} = n + n(nx)^2 + \frac{2n}{3} (nx)^4 + \frac{17n}{45} (nx)^6 + \cdots = n\sec^2 nx$$

since the McLauren series for $\sec nx$ is

$$\sec nx = 1 + \frac{1}{2} (nx)^2 + \frac{5}{24} (nx)^4 + \frac{61}{720} (nx)^6 +\cdots$$

Using Euler's identity:

$$e^{inx} = \cos nx + i \sin nx$$

$$\frac{d e^{inx}}{dx}=n i e^{i n x} = n ( i \cos nx - \sin nx)$$

Equating the real and imaginary parts:

$$\frac{d \cos nx}{dx} = -n \sin nx, \quad \frac{d \sin nx}{dx} = n\cos nx$$